# How do I make \hat{i} pretty?

Tags: accents

I'm looking for a way to make the hat in `\hat{i}` replace the dot. I can't find anything on Google, and am seemingly too dumb to figure it out myself.

Comment: Mabye `\hat{\i}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: it seems I am having a bit of a problem, `$\hat{\J}$` is simply the same as `$\J$`. Please help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The dotless `i` is available as `\imath`, and similarly `\jmath` for a dotless `j`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\I}{\imath}
\newcommand*{\J}{\jmath}

\begin{document}
$\hat{\I}$, $\hat{\J}$
\end{document}
```